# Form validation of numeric characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to perform form validation using JavaScript to check for input field only to contain numeric characters.So far, the validation checks for the field not being empty - which works fine.However, numeric characters validation is not working.I would be grateful for any help.Many thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//form validation
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["cdp_form"]["univer_number"].value
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("University number (URN) field must be filled in");
  cdp_form.univer_number.focus();
  return false;
  }
else if (is_valid = /^[0-9]+$/.test(x))
    {
    alert("University number (URN) field must have numeric characters");
    cdp_form.univer_number.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
</script>


<input type ="text" id="univer_number" maxlength="7"    size="25"   name="univer_number" />
```

Comment: "Not working" is a poor way to describe a problem. What is not working? Are you getting errors?

Comment: It doesn't provide validation error which I wanted. Don't worry the problem has been solved - see accepted answer.

Comment: I worry, as I hope your next questions have better descriptions. http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test for the negation of the RegExp because you want the validation to alert upon failure, so just add `!` in front of it:

```
else if (is_valid = !/^[0-9]+$/.test(x))
```

[See example →](http://jsfiddle.net/EEZbd/)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.It works - very easy to overlook such a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Your test condition is a bit strange:

```
else if (is_valid = /^[0-9]+$/.test(x))
```

Why have the redundant comparison to `is_valid`? Just do:

```
else if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(x))
```

Though the regex you are using will match numerals and only numerals - you need to change it to match anything that is *not* a numeral - like this `/^[^0-9]+$/`.

Better yet, get rid of the regex altogether and use [`IsNumeric`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/1830844#1830844):

```
else if (!IsNumeric(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using Regex, if it must only be numerals you can simply use IsNumeric in Javascript.

```
IsNumeric('1') => true; 
IsNumeric('145266') => true;
IsNumeric('abc5423856') => false;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need invert your regular expression (add ^ inside [0-9]):

```
/^[^0-9]+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

On your line that says `else if (is_valid = /^[0-9]+$/.test(x))`, you're doing a simple assignment instead of testing that it is actually matching the regex.

Comment: As strange as it seems, it still yields the correct result (at least fiddling in chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern will still accept this input `<b>#@$@#123` or `ad!@#12<b>`. Use this pattern I created:

```
/[a-zA-Z-!@#$%^&*()_+\=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/
```

This pattern will check if it is alphabetic and special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I thought I'd post what worked for me. I don't require the field to be filled at all but if it is it has to be numerical:

```
function validateForm()
{
 var x=document.forms["myformName"]["myformField"].value;

if (/[^0-9]+$/.test(x))
    {
    alert("Please enter a numerical amount without a decimal point");
    myformName.myformField.focus();
    return false;
  } 
}
```